# expectation of function of geometric random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

This is question **3a** from [this sample test](http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/464_07/sample1_464.pdf)

> Let $X$ be a geometric RV with mean 2. Compute $E[e^{−X}]$

If I could convert this to a sum (by knowing the probabilities of each term?), then perhaps I could do this problem, but I only know the mean of X.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a Geometric Random Variable?

Comment: Yes: the number of trials till first success, with P(success) = p. P(X=k) = p(1-p)^k-1

Comment: And when the mean is 2, what is p?

Comment: .5; I saw that you led me there. But the given answer still eludes me

Comment: And from the definition of an expected value, $E(f(X))=\sum f(X)P(X=x)$ can you finish?

Comment: I get r = 1/(2e) in a geom series, but r should be 2e -1

Comment: You want to find $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(\tfrac 1{2e})}^k = ....$

Comment: I can't yet get to the answer 1/(2e -1). instead I get 2e/(2e-1)

Answer (score 1):

We know from definition of the moment generating function of $X$ which is Geometrically distributed, that: $$E[e^{tX}]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{tk}\left (\frac 12 \right)^k=\frac {\frac 12e^t} {{1-e^t \left(\frac 12 \right)}}$$

Now $t=-1$ and we simplify...

Comment: got it finally from here. Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 0):

As a 1-shifted geometric random variable, $X$ has probability mass function for some rate parameter $p$ : $$\mathsf P(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1} p~\mathbf 1_{k\in\Bbb N^+}$$

The expectation of $X$ being $2$ should tell you what value of $p$ you have.

Now, by definition of expectation (and the Law of the Unconcious Statastitian):

$$\mathsf E(\mathsf e^{-X}) ~{= \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k} \mathsf P(X=k) \\ = \frac p{1-p}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1-p}e\right)^{k} \\ = \phantom{~ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2e}\right)^{k}}}$$

Comment: Getting from step 1 to step 2 here is beyond me right now

Comment: Eh, @cumin  It's just $\sum\limits_{k} e^{-k}(1-p)^{k-1}p = p(1-p)^{-1}\sum\limits_k e^{-k}(1-p)^k$

Comment: :-)  Thank you thank you.